# Access name of object being wrapped, in Swift property wrapper implementation

Tags: swift, property-wrapper

I'm using Swift property wrappers to define something like:

```
@MyWrapper var foo: Int
```

And in the implementation of the property wrapper, I'd like to access the name of the variable, foo, as a string. Something like this:

```
@propertyWrapper
public struct MyWrapper<Type> {
  init() {
    // Get access to "foo" -- name of var as String
  }
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: I'm almost certain there's no API for doing that.

Comment: Could this be an xy question? What’s the real goal?

Comment: `xy` question? In the @propertyWrapper implementation I need a name that I use to store data in, say, user defaults-- specific to this property. I can (and am doing this now) pass the name as an init parameter. But, it seems cleaner to at least give a parameter default that's the name of the variable.

Comment: I'm in a similar situation.  Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Need something like `#var`, analogous to `#function` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402533/is-there-a-swift-alternative-for-nslogs-pretty-function). I need to put this on the Swift dev forum.

Comment: Some ideas here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114064/swift-reflection-capabilities-how-to-get-an-instance-variable-name but haven't tried this.

Comment: Interested in this and hoping there can be an answer!

Comment: This should be solvable now with Swift macros!

Answer (score 1):

To pass variable name to the wrapper; you can use this alternative way.

```
@propertyWrapper
public struct MyWrapper<Type> {

  var wrappedValue: ... {
  set{.....}
  get{.....}
  }

  init(wrappedValue initialValue: Double, _ nameOfTheVariable: String ) {
      precondition(!nameOfTheVariable.isEmpty)
      //you can access nameOfTheVariable here
  }  
}
```

then use it like below,

```
   @MyWrapper("foo") var foo: Int
```

Note: in the init method mentioning wrappedValue is a must. Unless , It didn't work for me.

(*init(**wrappedValue** initialValue: Double, _ nameOfTheVariable: String )* )

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @Yodagama. However, this isn't quite what I asked. This isn't the "name of the variable" exactly. It's another string passed as a parameter. It isn't quite as good notationally, and the API user of the wrapper has to know what to pass in-- the redundant name of the variable.

Comment: @ChrisPrince yeah i agree